# Seeding mongoose (MongoDB) database with typescript

Tags: typescript, mongoose, seeding

There are plenty of projects out there that help to seed a MongoDB with NodeJS, but none that are natively TypeScript. What would be the best way to seed data programatically via TypeScript?

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on it, I have a seederScript that looks like this

```
require("dotenv").config();

import { ProductsData } from "./data/products"; //dummy data
import connectDB from "./config/db";
import Product from "./models/product";

connectDB();

const importData = async (): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    await Product.deleteMany({});

    await Product.insertMany(ProductsData);

    console.log("Data Import Success");

    process.exit();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error with data import", error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

importData();
```

and when I try to run this script with node `node src/seederScript` I'm getting this error `Cannot find module...` . I'm getting many different errors however I try and I don't know what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your project first, and then run the `.js` version of your seed file. Here is an example of how you might set it up with scripts in your `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --exec ts-node './src/server.ts'",
    "build": "rm -rf dist/ && tsc --project './tsconfig.build.json'",
    "start": "pnpm build && NODE_ENV=production node --trace-warnings './dist/server.js'",
    "watch": "tsc --project './tsconfig.build.json' --watch",
    "db:seed": "pnpm build && node './dist/db/seed-database.js'",
    "db:clear": "pnpm build && node './dist/db/seed-database.js -c'", 
...
```